# SQL Server 2008 R2: selecting record which are present in another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a main table `tbl_user` and a temporary table `tbl_user_temp`.
`tbl_user` contains records in which some are duplicated, so I've moved these records to the temporary table using this query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_user_temp
   SELECT    
      *    
   FROM    
      tbl_user    
   GROUP BY     
      fullname, username, password    
   HAVING 
      COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now what I want to do is to delete the records from `tbl_user` which are present in the `tbl_user_temp`

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Even you apply the delete you will end up deleting both records for matching values.

Comment: can you give us examples of your data?

Comment: Just get the distinct records and copy to temp table and then truncate the main table and copy back the temp data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you want to remove all the duplicate records from the your main table.
This solution allows you to delete one row from each set of duplicates (rather than just handling a single block of duplicates at a time):

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT username, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
    fullname,username,password  
    ORDER BY username)
  FROM dbo.tbl_user    
)
DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;
```

The [Row_Number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx) Will genrate the partitions wise row number. And for each same group the row number will be there.
And in the `DELETE x WHERE rn > 1;` there it will check if the rownumber is is greater that 1 it will delete that row. If youu just use `Select` in place of `delete` query you will see how it generates the rownumber.

Comment: @Andomar your code works perfectly. however i'm not familiar with this kind of query, can you explain it bro?

Comment: Thanks dude! It generates a record set which has **username** and **rn** field, I understand now. You're the man! from outer space

Answer (score 1):

No need for a temporary table:

```
delete  u
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by fullname, username, password
                    order by newid()) as rn
        from    tbl_user
        ) u
where   rn > 1
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1b034/1/0)